# how to instantiate and use a dma driver linux module

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, fpga

we are working on a Xilinx Zynq FPGA custom DMA device to process lots of data fast. We were able to make it all work on bare-metal, but have trouble in Linux.
We work on ARM linux kernel 3.9. We do not know how to instantiate and use the kernel driver for our device:
https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx/blob/master/drivers/dma/xilinx/xilinx_axidma.c
Does any of you have suggestions or some example code they can share?

Right now we plan to use some of the code here:
http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt

But we are not sure how to instantiate the struct device.

Answer (score 5):

I think in the xilinx_axidma.c codes, the xdev->dev and chan->dev has already been initialized  to &(op->dev). You can pass the xdev->dev or chan->dev as the first parameter to DMA APIs. There is no need to create a DMA buffer pool yourself in the xilinx_axidma.c. In a word, the initialization has been done correctly. You can go ahead to using DMA APIs. Maybe you will create a Tx/Rx buffer ring instead of one buffer. Since the FPGA chip DMA controller uses the physical address, while the kernel module uses the virtual address. So you have to create some kind of structures to maintain both the vaddrs and paddrs for all buffers in the buffer rings, such as BD/buffer approach.

(1) How to allocate one DMA buffer:

```
  vaddr = (unsigned long) dma_alloc_coherent(xdev->dev, size, paddr, GFP_KERNEL);
```

The return value is the virtual address of the allocated DMA buffer, and paddr stores the physical address of it. The FPGA chip DMA controller uses the paddr, while the kernel module uses the vaddr.

(2) After received the data from FPGA, call following function to invalidate the D-Cache:

```
  dma_unmap_single(xdev->dev, paddr, length, DMA_FROM_DEVICE);
```

The paddr is the physical address of the DMA buffer.

(3) Before sending one buffer to FPGA, call following function to flush the D-cache:

```
  paddr = dma_map_single(xdev->dev, vaddr, length, DMA_TO_DEVICE);
```

The paddr is the physical address of the DMA buffer, the vaddr is the virtual address of the DMA buffer.

(4) Get a receive buffer's physical address:

```
  paddr = dma_map_single(xdev->dev, vaddr, length, DMA_FROM_DEVICE);
```

(5) How to free one DMA buffer:

```
  dma_free_coherent(xdev->dev, size, vaddr, paddr);
```

The vaddr is the virtual address of the DMA buffer, whereas the paddr is the physical address.